# sending mail through controller (using gmail)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, smtpclient

So, first time attempting to send mail from a mvc application and lo and behold, it didn't work :(

Here's the spaghetti I've whipped up so far from some sources, needless to say I end up in the Error View:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(Contact c)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(c.Email.ToString());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            msg.To.Add("myaddress@mail.com");
            msg.Subject = "New Message";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myaddress@mail.com", "mypassword");

            sb.Append("Name: " + c.Name);
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("Email: " + c.Email);
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("Message: " + c.Message);

            msg.Body = sb.ToString();
            smtp.Send(msg);
            msg.Dispose();

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
                return View("Error");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: The tutorial I used didn't provide an error view so it just returns a view I created that says "Error". I'm not sure what else to add to that catch statement that can give me something useful.

Comment: Change your catch block  to  `catch (Exception ex){ return Content(ex.Message); }` to see the exception message. That will help you to understand what exception is happening. Also you may put a break point inside that to inspect the variable `ex`

Comment: @Shyju It's telling me a from address must be specified but I'm having the user insert their address and in the controller its `MailAddress from = new MailAddress(c.Email.ToString());`

Comment: Where are you setting the 'from' address on the message? msg.From....??